# jq: repeat value from one object when iterating over array elements in another object

Tags: jq

Input:

```
{
  "level1": {
    "id": "a"
  },
  "level2": [
    {
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "2"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "level1": {
    "id": "b"
  },
  "level2": [
    {
      "id": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": "4"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
a  1 
a  2 
b  3 
b  4
```

What I basically want to accomplish is:

```
jq -r '[ .level1.id, (.level2[] |.id ) ]|@tsv'
```

where .level1.id repeats for every object in the .level2 array but I don't seem to be able to think about the problem the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.level2[]` within another array constructor (the outer `[…]`) just collects all items iterated over into that constructed array. Separate them to iterate outside another array, make both parts create (sub)arrays themselves, then add them together:

```bash
[.level1.id] + (.level2[] | [.id]) | @tsv
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ZzFnD6iWhPb)

Alternatively, use variables which you can reference from inside the array constructor:

```bash
.level2[] as {$id} | [.level1.id, $id] | @tsv
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/9VAENdDCvpm)

Output:

```
a   1
a   2
b   3
b   4
```

Comment: My actual data is fairly complex -- the variables was exactly what I needed

Comment: No matter how complex, both approaches would work. But I agree that readability increases with shorter clauses, which can be produced more easily using the variable approach. Here's the other way round if you wanted to "hold" the level 1 value while iterating over level2: `.level1 as {$id} | .level2[] | [$id, .id] | @tsv`. Sometimes, "holding" both, and assembling the final output array by only using variables may be even more readable (albeit longer in total): `.level1.id as $id1 | .level2[].id as $id2 | [$id1, $id2] | @tsv`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the first-level id into an array, then append each id from the second level:

```
[.level1.id] + (.level2[]|[.id]) | @tsv
```